# overriding password controller in devise not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have problems when overriding passwords controller in devise. I do not want to sign in the user after password is changed so i thought of overriding the password controller and i tried as follows and got an error. I could not identify what the problem is, so please help me. The following is the passwords_controller.rb

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
    prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication
    # Render the #edit only if coming from a reset password email link
    append_before_filter :assert_reset_token_passed, :only => :edit

    def new
      super
    end

    def create
        super
    end

    def edit
        self.resource = resource_class.new
        resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
    end

    def update
        self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)

        if resource.errors.empty?
            flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
            set_flash_message(:notice, "New password has been saved")
            redirect_to new_user_session_path
            else
            respond_with resource
        end
    end

    protected

    # The path used after sending reset password instructions
    def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
        new_session_path(resource_name)
    end

    # Check if a reset_password_token is provided in the request
    def assert_reset_token_passed
        if params[:reset_password_token].blank?
            set_flash_message(:error, :no_token)
            redirect_to new_session_path(resource_name)
        end
    end

    # Check if proper Lockable module methods are present & unlock strategy
    # allows to unlock resource on password reset
    def unlockable?(resource)
        resource.respond_to?(:unlock_access!) &&
        resource.respond_to?(:unlock_strategy_enabled?) &&
        resource.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email)
    end
end
```

and my routes is

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => 'passwords' }
```

and the error i get is

```
NameError in PasswordsController#update
undefined local variable or method `resource_params' for #<PasswordsController:0x000001008231c8>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works. I am using devise version 1.5.3 and it does not provide resource_params method so i copied the following from devise version 1.5.3 and it works.

> self.resource =
>   resource_class.reset_password_by_token(params[resource_name])

Answer (score 0):

Your 'resource_params' is undefined. May be you should get it as a parameter :

```
def update
    self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(params[:resource_params])
    ....
```

Comment: I have tried as you told and it shows different error                                "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
 You might have expected an instance of Array.
 The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]"